# Add block in left column if it was removed in the default file

Tags: blocks

I have a 2 columns - left layout for the `checkout_cart_index`. In the `checkout.xml` file, the left column is removed:

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <remove name="left"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

How can I add a block in the left column via `local.xml`?

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.polar.pagenav" template="catalog/navigation/pagenav.phtml"/>
</reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible out of the box with Magento once it is removed by default there isn't a XML command to add it back in.

If you install http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layout-unremove.html you can then add it back in your local.xml using something like

```
<your_handle_name>
    <x-unremove name="left" />
</your_handle_name>
```

Take a look at http://alanstorm.com/magento_layout_unremove_in_local_xml